# create associative array from db results array using array row as index

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I created db query that joins four tables and returns the following results in an array in codeigniter.

```
Array
(
[results] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [slip_id] => 257
                [slip_num] => 32
                [project_no] => SWS153
                [client_id] => 1
                [dwg_id] => 1
                [user_id] => 1
                [issue_date] => 2015-10-25 15:00:32.000000
                [sws_dwg_no] => SWS153-100
                [client_dwg_no] => 
                [dwg_title] => Pipework Suction and  Discharge: General Arrangement
                [dwg_by] => 
                [dwg_rev] => D
                [dwg_date] => 2015-10-25 15:00:32
                [rev_id] => 143
                [clientName] => R
                [clientSurname] => C
                [clientCom] => Pumps and Valves (Pty.) Ltd.
                [id] => 1
                [email] => admin@domain.com
                [password] => 5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99
                [name] => Admin
                [lastname] => Admin
                [project_name] => Metalong Raw Water Pump Station
            )

            [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [slip_id] => 258
                [slip_num] => 32
                [project_no] => SWS153
                [client_id] => 1
                [dwg_id] => 2
                [user_id] => 1
                [issue_date] => 2015-10-25 15:00:32.000000
                [sws_dwg_no] => SWS153-107
                [client_dwg_no] => 
                [dwg_title] => Pipework isolation valve chamber & surg vessel
                [dwg_by] => 
                [dwg_rev] => D
                [dwg_date] => 2015-10-25 15:00:32
                [rev_id] => 144
                [clientName] => R
                [clientSurname] => C
                [id] => 1
                [email] => admin@domain.com
                [password] => 5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99
                [name] => Admin
                [lastname] => Admin
                [project_name] => Metalong Raw Water Pump Station
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [slip_id] => 259
                [slip_num] => 32
                [project_no] => SWS153
                [client_id] => 1
                [dwg_id] => 3
                [user_id] => 1
                [issue_date] => 2015-10-25 15:00:32.000000
                [sws_dwg_no] => SWS153-112
                [client_dwg_no] => 
                [dwg_title] => Pipework discharge pipe pieces plan and details
                [dwg_by] => 
                [dwg_rev] => D
                [dwg_date] => 2015-10-25 15:00:32
                [rev_id] => 145
                [clientName] => R
                [clientSurname] => C
                [id] => 1
                [email] => admin@domain.com
                [password] => 5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99
                [name] => Admin
                [project_name] => Metalong Raw Water Pump Station
            )

        [3] => stdClass Object
            (
                [slip_id] => 260
                [slip_num] => 32
                [project_no] => SWS153
                [client_id] => 1
                [dwg_id] => 4
                [user_id] => 1
                [issue_date] => 2015-10-25 15:00:32.000000
                [sws_dwg_no] => SWS153-113
                [client_dwg_no] => 
                [dwg_title] => Pipework suction and discharge setting out layout
                [dwg_by] => 
                [dwg_rev] => D
                [dwg_date] => 2015-10-25 15:00:32
                [rev_id] => 146
                [clientName] => R
                [clientSurname] => C
                [id] => 1
                [email] => admin@domain.com
                [password] => 5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99
                [name] => Admin
                [project_name] => Metalong Raw Water Pump Station
            )

        [4] => stdClass Object
            (
                [slip_id] => 261
                [slip_num] => 32
                [project_no] => SWS153
                [client_id] => 3
                [dwg_id] => 1
                [user_id] => 1
                [issue_date] => 2015-10-25 15:00:32.000000
                [sws_dwg_no] => SWS153-100
                [client_dwg_no] => 
                [dwg_title] => Pipework Suction and  Discharge: General Arrangement
                [dwg_by] => 
                [dwg_rev] => D
                [dwg_date] => 2015-10-25 15:00:32
                [rev_id] => 143
                [clientName] => F
                [clientSurname] => N
                [id] => 1
                [email] => admin@domain.com
                [password] => 5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99
                [name] => Admin 
                [project_name] => Metalong Raw Water Pump Station
            )

        [5] => stdClass Object
            (
                [slip_id] => 262
                [slip_num] => 32
                [project_no] => SWS153
                [client_id] => 3
                [dwg_id] => 2
                [user_id] => 1
                [issue_date] => 2015-10-25 15:00:32.000000
                [sws_dwg_no] => SWS153-107
                [client_dwg_no] => 
                [dwg_title] => Pipework isolation valve chamber & surge vessel
                [dwg_by] => 
                [dwg_rev] => D
                [dwg_date] => 2015-10-25 15:00:32
                [rev_id] => 144
                [clientName] => F
                [clientSurname] => N
                [id] => 1
                [email] => admin@domain.com
                [password] => 5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99
                [name] => Admin
                [project_name] => Metalong Raw Water Pump Station
            )

        [6] => stdClass Object
            (
                [slip_id] => 263
                [slip_num] => 32
                [project_no] => SWS153
                [client_id] => 3
                [dwg_id] => 3
                [user_id] => 1
                [issue_date] => 2015-10-25 15:00:32.000000
                [sws_dwg_no] => SWS153-112
                [client_dwg_no] => 
                [dwg_title] => Pipework discharge pipe pieces plan and details
                [dwg_by] => 
                [dwg_rev] => D
                [dwg_date] => 2015-10-25 15:00:32
                [rev_id] => 145
                [clientName] => F
                [clientSurname] => N
                [id] => 1
                [email] => admin@domain.com
                [password] => 5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99
                [name] => Admin
                [project_name] => Metalong Raw Water Pump Station
            )

        [7] => stdClass Object
            (
                [slip_id] => 264
                [slip_num] => 32
                [project_no] => SWS153
                [client_id] => 3
                [dwg_id] => 4
                [user_id] => 1
                [issue_date] => 2015-10-25 15:00:32.000000
                [sws_dwg_no] => SWS153-113
                [client_dwg_no] => 
                [dwg_title] => Pipework suction and discharge setting out layout
                [dwg_by] => 
                [dwg_rev] => D
                [dwg_date] => 2015-10-25 15:00:32
                [rev_id] => 146
                [clientName] => F
                [clientSurname] => N
                [id] => 1
                [email] => admin@domain.com
                [password] => 5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99
                [name] => Admin
                [project_name] => Metalong Raw Water Pump Station
            )

    )

 )
```

I want to create an associative array using the client_id so I can group al the information for a client together and display it together. This is to produce a receipt. The same documents can be sent to different clients, so the receipt must be displayed per client.

I have tried to create a foreach loop to reorganize the array.

Comment: so what's your problem, are u reorganize your array with foreach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will group the results into an array, the original array is called $arr:

```
$result = array();
foreach( $arr['results'] as $v ) {
    $result[$v->client_id][] = $v;
}
```

To get a single clients ($client_id) all result display them like this

```
foreach( $result[$client_id] as $res ) {
    // Use the data
    echo 'Slip: ' .  $res->slip_id . "<br />\n"
        . 'Title: ' . $res->dwg_title  . "<br />\n";
}
```

To display everything, ordered by client, do somethoing like:

```
foreach( $result as $client_id => $temp ) {
    echo 'Client_id: ' . $client_id . "<br />\n";
    foreach( $temp as $res ) {
        // Use the data
        echo 'Slip: ' .  $res->slip_id . "<br />\n"
            . 'Title: ' . $res->dwg_title  . "<br />\n";
    }
}
```

Is this an answer to your question?

**Edit2** `$res` is an object...

A way to display a single client and a way to display all clients!

Comment: OP asked for an associative array but this should provide the same result

Comment: @Hasse Thanks for your help. The first part of the code that you provided me with worked and gave me a rearranged array according to `$client_id`. I'm struggling with the next bit to pass the array to my view.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the last part was in error. Of course it is an associative array, not an object. I have updated the script to show this!

Comment: @HasseBjörk So I've tried the updated code, but I keep running into problems to display it. I manage to get the post array of the `$client_id` from the previous view with which I create a `$client` array and pass to `foreach($result[$client] as $res){...}`. But I keep getting a **Illegal offset type** error. Unmodified Post array (client array) - `Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [client_id] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [client_id] => 3
        )

)`

Comment: What are you trying to do with the data? Display a single client or display all clients?

Comment: I do not use codeigniter, so I can not help you with the final view.